# Интеграция C# и Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Вот это мой код!

```js
function commandResult(){                
                   (function(callback){
                    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhttp.open("POST", 'http://127.0.0.1:11005/scan/', true);
                    //здесь получаю количество для сканирования
                    xhttp.send("<%=ScanPageCount()%>");
                    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()    
                                        {      
                                                if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
                                                callback(xhttp.responseText);    
                                        };                                                
                            })(function(respMessage)  
                            { 
                                 console.log(respMessage);
                                 document.getElementById('myPXText').value=respMessage;
                                ///здесь получаю и передаю в C# функцию 
                                ///сканированный текст
                                 var tmp = '<%=ImageScan(myPXText.Text)%>';
                            })
                    }
```

Этот код исползуется в системе `AcumaticaERP`
В системе  `AcumaticaERP` у меня две функции `ScanPageCount()` и `ImageScan()`

```
 public string ScanPageCount()
    {
         //передает каличество для сканирования 
        return  this.MyPanel.Current.PageCount.ToString();
    }
    public void ImageScan(string[] jstr)
    {
        //получает ответ сервера то есть сканированные картинки и  
         //делает какуэ то работу
    }
```

Но при этом сканированые не работает.
Как правильно реализовать это в системе Acumatica ERP.
Я не могу в метках помечать `acumatica` как это делать?